# Why can I still see encrypted data?

Tags: platform-encryption, shield

I have enabled Salesforce Shield in a developer org of mine, checked "Encrypted" in the custom field definition detail, and proceeded to update a record with a new value in the encrypted field.

I then attempted to login to Salesforce with another user, one that does not have "View Encrypted Data" permission enabled but can see see the field values that *should* be encrypted.

Can anyone explain why this may be?

I ran the Encryption Statistics and can see that 1 record has been encrypted (my test record), so it has definitely been encrypted. I've double checked that the second logged in users Profile doesn't have "View Encrypted Data" and there are no additional permission sets assigned to the account.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're confusing Salesforce Shield/Platform Encryption with Classic Encryption (encrypted fields).

The latter require the View Encrypted Data permission to view in plaintext, but that's not how Platform Encryption works. It's designed to encrypt data at rest for orgs that need it for compliance reasons, but it exists at a lower level than the field-by-field permissions. With Shield Platform Encryption, you still need to use field-level security to protect fields from users who shouldn't see them.

For more, see [Classic Encryption for Custom Fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/fields_about_encrypted_fields.htm) relative to [Strengthen Your Data's Security with Shield Platform Encryption](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_pe_overview.htm&type=5).

Comment: Let's say if we have FLS for the field as read, so they still be able to see the data, it won't show them as encrypted right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.